# Wordpress all posts from the last three days

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering if there is a way to limit wp_query´s result by the creation date? I only want to get all post not older than three days.

Comment: Yes you can. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I am pretty new to wordpress - so I havent tried anything useful =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WP_Query's date parameters to accomplish this.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => $threeDaysAgo,  
            'inclusive' => true,  
        ),  
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

After can take strtotime() compatible strings. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: No problem. You can also use the WP_Query parameters with the get_posts() function if you don't want to change the query object directly.